# User logs in to Windows XP, one application needs to start up automatically with admin rights

Tags: windows-xp

Multiple users use the same Windows XP PC. They have no admin rights, but after logging in they all need to use the same application that needs to be started with admin rights.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of possibilities:

- Look into using  `RunAs` with the `/savecred` switch. Be aware that this is a huge security hole though since if the user finds out that the credentials have been saved, they will be able to launch anything under the Administrator account using `RunAs`
- Launch the program via a VBScript that has the Administrator credentials in it. Use `screnc.exe` to encrypt the `.vbs` into a `.vbe`. It's easily decrypted though, plus Microsoft seem to have taken `screnc.exe` off their downloads area.

Comment: I've just realised that I've given you two options that you'd probably never want to use :/

Answer (score 1):

It's very rarely the case that the application *actually* needs to be run with admin privileges, but if that's actually the case here, consider running it under the `SYSTEM` account.

Otherwise, my preferred solution, after saving the system configs/doing a backup and warning/threatening the users is to grant user-level accounts the required permissions (usually `write` or `modify`) to the registry and/or file locations the program is trying to access.  If support for this products doesn't know what those locations are, you can find out with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Comment: +1 for this, grant the required permissions and no more. Spot on.